# Proof verification. Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let be $\left ( X,\tau \right )$ a path-connected space. Let be $\left ( X,{\tau}' \right )$ a space such that $\left ( X,{\tau}' \right ) \subset \left ( X, \tau \right )$ ($\tau$ is finer than ${\tau}'$). Show that $\left ( X,{\tau}' \right )$ is path-connected.

My attemp:

Let be $a,b \in \left ( X,{\tau}' \right )$. For all $x,y \in \left ( X,\tau \right )$ there is a path $f:\left [ 0,1 \right ] \rightarrow \left ( X,\tau \right )$ from $x$ to $y$, i.e. $f$ is continuous and $f\left ( 0 \right )=x$ and $f\left ( 1 \right )=y$. Particularly for $a,b \in \left ( X,\tau \right )$ there is a path $F:\left [ 0,1 \right ] \rightarrow \left ( X,\tau \right )$.

The identity function $i : \left ( X,\tau \right ) \rightarrow \left ( X,{\tau}' \right )$ is continuous because given $U\in{\tau}'$, $i^{-1}\left ( U \right ) = \left \{ x \in \left ( X,\tau \right )\mid i\left ( x \right )=x\in U \right \}=U$  is open in $\tau$ because ${\tau}' \subset \tau$. Then $i\circ F:\left [ 0,1 \right ] \rightarrow \left ( X,{\tau}' \right )$ is a path from $a$ to $b$.

Therefore $\left ( X,{\tau}' \right )$ is path-connected.

If I'm wrong give me a hint to be right, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: It's correct. However, you may fine tune your notation: the elements of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ live in the underlying set $X$. [so you could have just written $a,b\in X$ and $f:[0,1] \to X $].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the idea is essentially that making the topology in the codomain smaller, any continuous function stays continuous. Your proof is correct. Recap:

So let $a,b \in X$. By path continuity of $(X,\tau)$ there is a continuous $p: [0,1] \to (X,\tau)$ with $p(0)=a, p(1)=b$. As $\tau' \subseteq \tau$, that same map regarded as $p: [0,1] \to (X,\tau')$ is also continuous (as $O \in \tau' \to O \in \tau \to p^{-1}[O] \text{ open in } [0,1]$) and so that $p$ is a path from $a$ to $b$ in $(X,\tau')$ as well. As $a,b$ were arbitrary, $(X,\tau')$ is path-connected.